# Directing QT Gui from non-main thread

Tags: qt, qt5

I know the following isn't the normal Qt pattern, but I'd like to create/direct a main-thread GUI element from a non-main-thread.

The goal is to launch a standalone thread that lives for a long time and does its own thing.  I don't want to put hooks in my main window for every conceivable GUI thing a sub thread might do.  I want the sub thread to be able to show asynchronous notifications for example, deal with things in the background with progress bars, etc.

I create a worker object and move it to the secondary thread.  When the thread starts it signals to the worker object to instantiate a wrapper for a `QProgressDialog` to simulate the secondary thread 'doing its own thing'.  This wrapper then gets moved back to the main thread, and an event is posted which causes the wrapper to actually create the `QProgressDialog`, which happens in the main thread.  So far so good.  Then from within a long running loop in the secondary thread I emit a signal, expecting it to cross the thread boundary and update the `QProgressDialog`.  The signal does appear to arrive at the main loop's lambda which is connected to the signal, but it
doesn't arrive at the object which was moved to the main thread.  Interestingly, I *can* post an event to update the progress, so I know the event loop is running.  I have tried numerous variations of default and queued connections, connecting before and after moving to a new thread, without the actual gui component (just debug text), stack-based vs. heap objects, etc.  My understanding is that Qt automatically determines if the receiving object is in a different thread from the sending object, and if so, posts an event which is picked up by the event loop.  Could the issue be that I start the main thread (`QApplication::exec()`) after starting my sub thread?

In the below code, the debug msg in main.cpp correctly receives the events and prints the message, so the signal is crossing the thread boundary.  It's just not reaching my wrapper object.  Why not?

thanks.

Main.cpp

```
#include "task.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TestClass worker("Tc1");
    QThread *thr = new QThread;

    QObject::connect(thr, &QThread::started, &worker, &TestClass::doWork);
    QObject::connect(&worker, qOverload<int,int>(&TestClass::progress), [](int x, int y){
        qDebug() << x << "out of" << y;});
    QObject::connect(&worker, &TestClass::done, []{qDebug() << "Done";});

    worker.moveToThread(thr);

    thr->start();
    a.exec();
    thr->wait();
    thr->quit();
    qDebug("Done");

}
```

task.h

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <QProgressDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

static const QEvent::Type CREATE = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::User + 0);
static const QEvent::Type SET_VALUE = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::User + 1);

// Wraps QProgressDialog
// Create an instance, then move to another thread
class ProgressDialogWrapper : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QProgressDialog *mWidget;
    QString mLabelText;
    QString mCancelButtonText;
    int mMinimum;
    int mMaximum;
    QWidget *mParent;
    const Qt::WindowFlags mF;
    void create() {mWidget = new QProgressDialog(mLabelText, mCancelButtonText,
                                                 mMinimum, mMaximum, mParent, mF);}
public:
    ProgressDialogWrapper(const ProgressDialogWrapper &) {}
    ~ProgressDialogWrapper() override {
        qDebug() << "ProgressDialogWrapper destructor";
    }
    ProgressDialogWrapper(const QString &labelText,
                          const QString &cancelButtonText,
                          int minimum,
                          int maximum,
                          QWidget *parent = nullptr,
                          Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags()) :
        mWidget(nullptr),
        mLabelText(labelText),
        mCancelButtonText(cancelButtonText),
        mMinimum(minimum),
        mMaximum(maximum),
        mParent(parent),
        mF(f) {}
    ProgressDialogWrapper(QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags()) :
        mWidget(nullptr),
        mParent(parent),
        mF(f){}
    QProgressDialog *widget() {return mWidget;}
    // Receiving events works across thread boundary
    bool event(QEvent *e) override {
        switch(e->type()) {
            case QEvent::User:
                create();
                mWidget->show();
                return true;
            case SET_VALUE:
                mWidget->setValue(mWidget->value() + 1);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

public slots:
    // These slots don't seem to work across thread boundary
    void show() {mWidget->show();}
    void setMaximum(int x) {mWidget->setMaximum(x);}
    void setMinimum(int x) {mWidget->setMinimum(x);}
    void setValue(int x) {
        qDebug() << "setValue";
        mWidget->setValue(x);
    }
    void requestValue() {emit requestedValue(mWidget->value());}
signals:
    void requestedValue(int);
};

// This didn't help
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ProgressDialogWrapper)


class TestClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString name;
public:
    TestClass() {}
    TestClass(QString n) : name(n) {}
    ~TestClass() override {
        qDebug() << "TestClass destructor";}
public slots:
    void doWork() {
        int loopcount = 10;
        ProgressDialogWrapper pdw("LabelText", "TheButton", 0, loopcount, nullptr);
        pdw.moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
        bool okc = QObject::connect(this, qOverload<int>(&TestClass::progress),
                         &pdw, &ProgressDialogWrapper::setValue,
                         Qt::QueuedConnection);
        qDebug() << "connect:" << okc;
        emit progress(5); // nope this doesn't work
        QApplication::postEvent(&pdw, new QEvent(CREATE));  // this does work

        std::chrono::milliseconds t(500);
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++) {
            // emitting to wrapper doesn't work -- no debug output            
            emit progress(i);
            
            // emitting to main.cpp lambda does work
            emit progress(i, loopcount);
            
            // Posting event works -- progress bar is updated
            QApplication::postEvent(&pdw, new QEvent(SET_VALUE));

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(t);
            QApplication::processEvents(); // no effect, I just made this up in desperation
        }
        emit done();
    }
signals:
    void progress(int);
    void progress(int, int);
    void done();
};


#endif // TASK_H
```

I'm also considering sending a `QEvent` derivative which can hold a lambda as an argument, then having that run in the main thread, but I haven't explored that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your `ProgressDialogWrapper::event` implementation...

```
bool event (QEvent *e) override
{
    switch(e->type()) {
    case QEvent::User:
        create();
        mWidget->show();
        return true;
    case SET_VALUE:
        mWidget->setValue(mWidget->value() + 1);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

You only ever process the `CREATE` and `SET_VALUE` cases: all other events are effectively discarded by this `ProgressDialogWrapper` instance including the `QEvent::MetaCall` events used by queued connections.

Replacing the current implementation with...

```
bool event (QEvent *e) override
{
    switch(e->type()) {
    case QEvent::User:
        create();
        mWidget->show();
        return true;
    case SET_VALUE:
        mWidget->setValue(mWidget->value() + 1);
        return true;
    default:

        /*
         * Defer to the base class implementation.
         */
        return return QObject::event(e);
    }
}
```

should fix the problem.